# Code executing only when breakpoints are active

Tags: ios, breakpoints

this is my first post on stackoverflow so i'll try to be as much clear as possible.
I'm a very beginner in iPhone developing so please excuse by advance if my question is a noob one.
Please excuse my english also...

I'm trying to show in some UITextLabel the date values immediately when UIViewController shows up.
But the dateLabel and hourLabel don't update. The code is executing well only if i put a breakpoint just after the super initialization.

*Calling the UIViewController CustomDatePicker*

```
- (IBAction)setStartPointClicked:(id)sender {

    _picker = [[CustomDatePicker alloc]initWithNibName:@"CustomDatePicker" bundle:nil];

    _picker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:_picker animated:YES completion:^{

    }] ;

}
```

*iniWithNibName method called to initialize the controller*

```
- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if(!self) {                                       //<=============Breakpoint
        return nil;
    }
    [self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString* str = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:_datePicker.date];
    [_dateLabel setText:str];
    NSLog(str);

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    str = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:_datePicker.date];
    [_hourLabel setText:str];
    NSLog(str);

    return self;
}
```

I think i'm trying to call properties before that they have the time to be assigned. If I put the breakpoint after each label string change it doesn't update. They are executing only if the breakpoint is placed beetween the super init and the code to execute. Does breakpoint is giving some time to my application to load objects?

Any ideas?
Thanks by advance

Comment: Hi @laperche, welcome to StackOverflow. Good work at writing down your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code into **viewDidLoad** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following changes:

```
// The init... method. This is the iOS standard way of writing it
- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if(self) {

    }

    return self;
}

// viewDidLoad method
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString* str = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
    [self.dateLabel setText:str];
    NSLog(str);

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    str = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:_datePicker.date];
    [self.hourLabel setText:str];
    NSLog(str);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it help a lot. It's working like a charm!!
thank you very much. I did'nt know that didViewLoad was automatically loading instead of calling it